# Implementing Framerate-independent Acceleration

Tags: timestamp, physics, frame-rate, frames, acceleration

I am attempting to make an HTML5 canvas-based game which involves framerate-independent motion (objects move at the same rate, regardless of FPS).

I know how to implement framerate-independent motion on an object moving at a constant rate. However, in my new game, objects don't move at a constant rate - they accelerate.

I want an object to accelerate at a speed of one pixel per second, so that at the end of each second, the object will be at a certain position, regardless of FPS, as shown below (starting from position = 0, velocity = 0:

```
Second 1: position: 1, velocity: 1
Second 2: position: 3, velocity: 2
Second 3: position: 6, velocity: 3
Second 4: position: 10, velocity: 4
...
```

Unless I am mistaken, this type of situation can be recreated with a formula such as `position += velocity += acceleration (1)`.

How can I implement this with framerate-independence?

Comment: Are you asking for a formula that gives position as a function of time?

Comment: Ideally, yes. It should consider the number of times per second (FPS) an update is required, as well as the acceleration per second (1 in any direction, in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If acceleration is constant **a**, and at time t=0 velocity is **V<sub>0</sub>** and position is **X<sub>0</sub>** then at some later time t the velocity and position will be:

**V** = **V<sub>0</sub>** + **a** t
**X** = **X<sub>0</sub>** + **V<sub>0</sub>** t + **a** t<sup>2</sup>/2

For example, if we take **a** = 1 and start at position = 0, velocity = 0, and we sample velocity and position at intervals of 1.0:

```
Second 1: position: 0.5  velocity: 1
Second 2: position: 2    velocity: 2
Second 3: position: 4.5  velocity: 3
Second 4: position: 8    velocity: 4
```

But we can calculate position and velocity for any time. The frame rate does not appear in the formula.

Comment: Can something similar to this be done so that, at each second, the position, rather than the velocity, remains constant? For instance, the positions should be 1, 3, 6, 10..., respectively.

Comment: @Nick362880: Yes, just set X0=0, V0=0.5, a=1, and you'll get x=1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21,...